# Use the cylindrical shell method to find the volume

Tags: calculus, integration

Okay so here i have a question:

> Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by
>   rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the y-axis.
>   $y = 5x^2$ ,    $y = 30x − 10x^2$

So i have my integral set up like this...

$\int_0^2 {something}$

I have the graph here (courtesy of wolfram)

[image]

So what i am having trouble is with what is suppose to go inside the integral? what am i suppose to integrate?

I understand since its the Cylindrical shell method i am suppose to chose a strip parallel to the axis i am revolving it around hence why my integral must go from `0` to `2`.

Do i simply just subtract the upper function - lower function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let be $f(x)=5x^2$ the upper limit and $g(x)=-10(x-3)x$ the lower limit.

Then the volume is then

$$V=2\pi\int_0^2\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|x\; \text d x$$

While when looking at your graph you can simplify $\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|=\left(f(x)-g(x)\right)$

Comment: This would give me a negative answer when i plugged all the values in. Does this sound about right?

Comment: Would the lower and upper limits be switched? because from the graph it shows the $10x-30x^2$ on top

Comment: Yeah you did get the upper and lower confused from 0 to 2 but when i fixed that the answer was correct. Thank you!